# What is $\int_{\lvert z\rvert=1} \mathrm{Log}(z)\,dz$?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, logarithms, contour-integration

> What is $\int_{\lvert z\rvert=1} \mathrm{Log}(z)\,dz$?

By letting $z = \mathrm{e}^{it}$, we get

$$\int_{\lvert z\rvert=1} \mathrm{Log}(z)\,dz = 
\int_0^{2\pi} \mathrm{Log}(\mathrm{e}^{it}) i\mathrm{e}^{it} dt = 
\int_0^{2\pi} (it) i\mathrm{e}^{it}\, dt = -\int_0^{2\pi}t\mathrm{e}^{it}\, dt 
 $$

Does this make sense? But since the function $\,\mathrm{Log}(z)$ is not analytic on $\{(x,0) : x\leq 0\}$, therefore it is not analytic at the point $(-1,0)$ which is on the contour. And I have read that contour integral does not make sense when there is a singularity on the contour.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does make sense.

Although $\log z$ is a multi-valued function and one might think that the value of the integral depends of the choice of the branch, in reality IT DOES NOT depend, as we simply and a constant, the contour integral of which if zero.

Comment: Isn't that assuming that the contour starts and ends at $z=1$? I don't know much about contour integration, but I'm guessing that if it starts at, say, $-1$ (meaning we have $\int_{-\pi}^\pi$) it's different.

Comment: It does not matter where we start, as long as we integrate over a closed contour - in complex integration.

Comment: Would it depend on the choice of branch cut, then?